# Multiple plots on page rezoom when resizing one

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have about 10 plots on a page all dynamically created. To save space they all start out small and users can press a button to "enlarge" them when they want to look at one closer. In both small and large modes users can zoom and manipulate however they want, but when a user zooms on one plot then toggles the size of another plot, the plot they are resizing "snaps" to the zoom profile of the first plot.

Hopefully I didn't explain that too confusingly. Here's a snippet of the code doing the resizing.

```
            $(document.getElementById(expArr[index])).click( function() {
                $(gd).toggleClass('clk');
                Plotly.Plots.resize(gd);
            });
```

expArr just holds the id of the buttons as they are dynamically created in the codebehind and gd holds the div that the plot is in. Toggleing the class of the div just changes the class that holds height/width.

All of the resizing works fine. It's just when you resize one plot and zoom, then resize a second plot, the second plot "snaps" to the zoom done on the first plot.

Comment: Can you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I'm sure if I would have posted more code someone would have noticed my mistake.

Basically I was using a function with a loop in it to draw all my plots on the page, but I had left my layout var outside of all that so it was the same object being reused for each plot. So when I called resize on a plot it saw that layout changed and updated to the new data.

Simply moving layout fixed the problem